# Image normalization: Issue with arithmetic operation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to normalize an image, I applied the formula to do so, however I encounter a weird arithmetic operation problem in doing so.

This is my code:

```
IM3=imread('mdb022.pgm');
i = IM3(:,:,1);
rtemp = min(i);         % find the min. value of pixels in all the columns (row vector)
rmin=min(rtemp)      % find the min. value of pixel in the image
rtemp = max(i);         % find the max. value of pixels in all the columns (row vector)
rmax=max(rtemp)      % find the max. value of pixel in the image
a=255;
b=rmax-rmin
m=a/b               % find the slope of line joining point (0,255) to (rmin,rmax)
c = 255 - m*rmax;       % find the intercept of the straight line with the axis
i_new = m*i + c;        % transform the image according to new slope
```

On the command window:

```
>> contrast_stretching_1

rmin =

    0


rmax =

  221


b =

  221


m =

    1
```

For the step m=a/b, the division should be 255 divided by 221, which is equal to 1.1538...., but why does matlab shows 1?

Can somebody enlighten me on this and help me solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing at all about Matlab so I am guessing that `m` has been truncated to an integer. What happens if you change `a` to `255.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your image to double (or single)

```
IM3 = imread('mdb022.pgm');
I   = double(IM3(:,:,1));
rmin = min(I(:));
rmax = max(I(:));
m = 255.0 ./ (rmax - rmin);
I_new = m.*(I - rmax) + 255.0;
% I_new = uint8(I_new); if you want the image as uint8
```